# Extract 7 numbers out of a random string

Tags: regular-expressions

I try to extract 7 numbers (a contract number) out of a random string using regex:

```
pattern contractNumberPattern = pattern.compile('[0-9]{7}'); 
Matcher contractNumberMatcher = contractNumberPattern.matcher('Test1234567Test');   
String contractNumber;
system.debug(contractNumberMatcher.find());
system.debug(contractNumberMatcher.matches());
system.debug(contractNumberMatcher.groupCount());
system.debug(contractNumberMatcher.group());
contractNumber = contractNumberMatcher.group(0);
system.debug(contractNumber);
```

Unfortunately this does not bring the desired result. the find() returns true but the groups are empty.

I tested my regex on a regex tester site and it bringt the right result. So ... where am I wrong?

Thanks and best,
Markus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [Pattern](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_pattern_methods.htm#apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_pattern_methods) and [Matcher](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_matcher_methods.htm) are fine, assuming you only ever want the first 7 numeric values in a String. The problem (even at compile time) is coming from your call to `matches()` in which the system class is looking to match an entire region, in your case `find()` is good enough. The following returns the first 7 numeric values, you can extend the length of such value by modifying the `{7}` parameter in the regex or can simply use `+` if you pre-validate the Contract numeric value length.

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile('([0-9]{7})');
Matcher matcher = pat.matcher('Test12345678Test');
Boolean matches = matcher.find();
System.debug(matcher.group(0));
```

An alternative to using [Patterns and Matchers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_using.htm), you can do some String manipulation with a classical for loop.

```
String contractNumber = 'Test12345678Test';
String numericString = '';
for(Integer i=0; i<contractNumber.length(); i++) {
    String character = contractNumber.mid(i, 1);
    if(character.isNumeric()) {
        numericString += character;
    }
}
System.debug('Contract number is: ' + numericString);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ... by doing too many system.debugs I prevented it from working *sigh